# How to install Kazam 1.5.3 in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, ubuntu-mate, kazam

My version is Kazam 1.4.5.

I tried [this](https://codeforgeek.com/how-to-record-screen-in-ubuntu-with-kazam/) link to update but I can't add ppa to my sources list due to this error:

```
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/sylvain-pineau/kazam/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Googling `ppa` for `sylvain-pineau` I [found](https://launchpad.net/%7Esylvain-pineau/+archive/ubuntu/kazam) that there is no release for `jammy` version.

Any solution there? or a better alternative for screen recorders?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: PPAs are 3rd party resources, so all checks are on you to perform. A quick look at https://launchpad.net/~sylvain-pineau/+archive/ubuntu/kazam should show no support for *jammy* or 22.04; did you look?

Comment: yes, I search and no available ppa....

Comment: so, I need another screen recorder I guess..

Comment: What is wrong with the version you have that is tested to work with the release that you have?

Comment: current version hasn't pause/stop controls and accepts only key combinations. Also has limited functions, no webcam, no live recording.